# Adding Custom marker in bar charts using iOS Charts Library

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I want to draw custom marker view on tapping bar on bar charts using iOS charts library. I create a view by subclassing MarkerView and also created xib of it. Now I want to add this marker like this. [Please click to see the marker designs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnmzQ.png). It is above bar graph connecting through a line. I am not able place that frame.

My customMarkerView.swift code is

```
class CustomMarkerView: MarkerView {
      override open func awakeFromNib() {
          self.offset.x = -self.frame.size.width / 2.0
          self.offset.y = -self.frame.size.height - 7.0
      }
      open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
          layoutIfNeeded()
      }
}
```

I am trying to add marker using this code

```
let marker: CustomMarkerView = (CustomMarkerView.viewFromXib() as? CustomMarkerView)!
marker.chartView = barChartView
barChartView.marker = marker
```

But my resulted graph looks like this [It is overlapping with the bounds of barChartView. please click to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFpzH.png) Any one knows how to do this

Comment: I think what you are looking for is baloonMarker. Please have a look at that class which is part of charts itself.

Comment: I am not able to customize balloonMarker according to my UI

Comment: @DivyaSaraswati are you able to set the frame to custom marker ?